# what should i do in order to make updater work?

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

```
    def main():
   
                  #Updater = Updater(key.api_key, use_context=True)
                 #dp = Updater.dispatcher

                #dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start_Command))

                 #dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.text,handle_message))

                 #dp.add_error_handler(error)

                 #Updater.start_polling()
                 #Updater.idle

main()

#but it says
```

Traceback:

File "c:\Users\21fin\Desktop\Python Learning\folder\main.py", line 20, in main
Updater = Updater(key.api_key,use_context=True)

```
      UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'Updater' where it is not associated with a value
```

The bot to run just fine as i wrote a clean code

Comment: Please format your question in a readable way and provide enough code so that one can actually try to reproduce the issue.